# jQuery - How to change the url without reloading?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Is there a way for jQuery to change the url without reloading?

Tried changing `window.location` and every time I change it, it automatically reloads the page.

Comment: you can use the plugin http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 1):

The only part of the url you can change without reloading is after the hash, `#`.  Any changes to the url before that will be considered a different page and will trigger a reload.